# Best practices on load a form inside a main form, both residing in an external DLL assembly

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-core, .net-assembly

I've loaded an external DLL into your project like this

```
Dim assembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(libraryPath & "filename.dll")
Dim type As Type = assembly.[GetType]("NameSpace.ClassName")

// i'm loading as a form here but can be any control
Dim frm As Form = TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance(type), Form)
```

What are the best practices if you're loading a class or a control inside the loaded form (above) that resides also inside the same assembly ?

**for instance:**
Lets say you loaded an assembly consisted of several forms. You load the assembly and create the instance of one of the forms, frm. But inside the loaded form, frm is also loaded another 2nd form, frm2 also belonging to the same assembly. How do i instantiate the second form? do i need to load the assembly again ?

**Edit**:
The assembly is a. Net 4.8 class library, that holds several forms, modules and abstract classes.  Is being loaded into a winforms also in. Net 4.8.
This question applies to both VB and C#. But on my case I'm coding on VB.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. Do you mean, you create a Control at run-time and add it to the Controls collection of the imported Form? Or are you setting the Parent? Anyway, the Control is created elsewhere, so you may need to dispose of it, the hosting form may not do it (e.g., you call `frm.ShowDialog()` and you have not created the instance with a using statement, i.e., `Using frm = TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance(type), Form) ... frm.Controls.Add([Control]) ...  End Using`). If your question is related to something more specific, be more specific.

Comment: Lets say you loaded an assembly consisted of several forms. You load the assembly and create the instance of one of the forms, frm. But inside the loaded form, frm is also loaded another 2nd form, frm2 also belonging to the same assembly. How do i instantiate the second form? do i need to load the assembly again ?

Comment: No, you don't. Use just `dim f2 as New Form2 f2.Show()` (in your `Form1` instance generated from the Library - assuming VB.Net, you can have a C# Library, of course). However, It's not clear in what context this application operates and how .Net Core is involved. Are both Projects developed using .Net Core 3.1+? Is the hosting app a .Net Core 3.1+ WinForms-based Solution (the starting Project is a WinForms one)? You cannot mix .Net Framework and .Net Core projects. BTW, to *ping* someone, you need to prefix a nickname with `@` (e.g., @Miguel Silva). I got here by chance.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi. I've edited the post for a better clarification as you suggested.

Comment: So, .Net Core is not involved here. It's .Net Framework, in both the assemblies. Have you thought about adding a Project Reference to the Library tat contains the Forms you want to load at run-time? It's quite simpler.

Comment: Otherwise, you can use the ApplicationEvents (`Project->Properties->ViewAppplicationEvents`), add a public class to `My.Application` (`Partial Friend Class MyApplication`) which, when first initialized, loads the Assembly. Let the class expose a public Function that accepts a Form name and use `Activator.CreateInstance` to return a Form instance by name. You can create the instance of this public class overriding the `StartUp` event, so it's initialized before the starting Form of your project.

Comment: hummm... thks...i'm going to digg on that. for all other reasons. And there's always the possibility of referencing it on the project and build the App that way. but this is not the case. My question remains: its an assembly outside of the project and it has several controls (forms) and public abstract classes. The case is: a form in the external assembly needs to load another form also inside the same assembly. How can i do that ?

Comment: Yes, well, you'll have to explain your scenario a lot better. Does the external Form already *know* that it has to load another Form from the same library? I assume it doesn't, since, if you tested it, you'd have seen that it can load a show a *local* Form without problem. So, do you want to, say, add a Button in ext-Form1 that load ext-Form2 and not, say, Form2 from your assembly? The more details you give me, the more details I can give you. Maybe I'll post an example of common operations, so you can tell me if it fits in scenario. Post the required details, though.

Comment: good point! 
(at this point i can't post any code since i'm in the middle of something. but i will.)
Actually the external form gave me an error stating it didn't recognise the other form from the same library.  How do i correct that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your external assembly in the StartUp event of your application.
Open `Project->Properties->Application` and click the `View Application Events` button.
This will open or generate the `ApplicationEvents.vb` class file (you'll see, in some comments, the events that are more often handled using the `My.Application` class).

Here, we add a handler to the StartUp event: this event is raised before the application startup form is loaded and shown.
We define a `Public` class object that references the external Library containing the Form resources.
This public class object is visible by all other classes in the Application, through the `My.Application` reference.
This class exposes a Public Method, `LoadForm()`, that allows to load an external Form  by Name.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        Public FormResources As ResourceBag

        Protected Overrides Function OnStartup(e As StartupEventArgs) As Boolean
            FormResources = New ResourceBag()
            Return MyBase.OnStartup(e)
        End Function

        Friend Class ResourceBag
            Private Shared libraryPath As String = "[Your Library path]"
            Private Shared asm As Assembly = Nothing
            Public Sub New()
                Dim resoursePath As String = Path.Combine(libraryPath, "[Your .dll Name].dll")
                If File.Exists(resoursePath) Then
                    asm = Assembly.LoadFile(resoursePath)
                End If
            End Sub

            Public Function LoadForm(formName As String) As Form
                If asm Is Nothing Then Throw New BadImageFormatException("Resource Library not loaded")
                Return TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance(asm.GetType($"[Library Namespace].{formName}")), Form)
            End Function
        End Class
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Now, let's assume you have a Form named `Form1` in your external library.
You can make `Form1` load another Form from the external Library or a Form from your assembly using either the `LoadForm()` method (it creates an instance of a Form in the external library) or the `New` keyword to create an instance of local Form class.

► If Form1 of the external Library already shows another Form from the same Library, e.g., clicking a Button, there's nothing we have to do: the external new Form is generated as usual.

In the sample code that follows, we are instead adding two Buttons to the external Form1 class:

- One Button loads a Form, `Form2`, from the external library, using the public method previously defined: `Using extForm1 As Form = My.Application.FormResources.LoadForm("Form1")`
- The other Button loads a Form also named `Form2`, which is instead part of the current Application, using the New keyword: `Dim f2 As New Form2()`

► The external Form1 instance is created with a Using statement because the `ShowDialog()` method is used to show the new Form: this requires that we dispose of the Form when it closes, otherwise it cannot dispose of itself when show like this.
If you use `Show()` or `Show(Me)`, the `Using` block needs to be removed otherwise the Form will be closed instantly. The Form and its Controls/components will be disposed of when it closes anyway.

► The `Form2` Form class of your Application cannot have Controls added from the Application Settings (these Control will be disposed of and generate an exception if the Form is shown a second time)

---

```
Using extForm1 As Form = My.Application.FormResources.LoadForm("Form1")
    If extForm1 IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim btnExt = New Button() With {
            .Location = New Point(20, 50),
            .Size = New Size(100, 30),
            .Text = "Lib Form2"
        }
        AddHandler btnExt.Click,
            Sub()
                Dim f2ext = My.Application.FormResources.LoadForm("Form2")
                f2ext.Show()
            End Sub

        Dim btn = New Button() With {
            .Location = New Point(140, 50),
            .Size = New Size(100, 30),
            .Text = "My Form2"
        }
        AddHandler btn.Click,
            Sub()
                Dim f2 As New Form2()
                f2.Show()
            End Sub

        extForm1.Controls.AddRange({btnExt, btn})
        btnExt.BringToFront()
        btn.BringToFront()
        extForm1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
        extForm1.ShowDialog(Me)
    End If
End Using
```

Comment: thank you @Jimi! a part from the initial, before startup form, loading of assemblies, my mind was also on that path. 
From the error i got on my project it was clear to me that any other form on the same assembly also needs to be loaded from the assembly as opposed to regular normal instantiation .

Comment: There are different ways to load a Form resource from a .dll. This is simple way. You can also use `My.MyApplication.ResourceBag.asm.DefinedTypes()`, which returns all types defined in the loaded assembly. You could filter based on the Form Type and map these types, so you could also use the Type Name to instatiate a Form object. It adds some complexity (but no real advantage, except the use of Forms Names). -- I'm not exactly sure what your comment is about.